# Order of updates in falling sand simulation

Tags: physics

Looking into the classic "falling sand" simulation I've run into a question that I couldn't find addressed anywhere.

Most people appear to agree that the update has to go bottom-up, because then an entire vertical column of sand can move down one pixel per update (because sand pixels that initially have a sand pixel beneath them can still fall down in the same update after that lower sand pixel was moved down earlier.)

(On the other hand if the update is top-down then only sand pixels with an air pixel will move down, leading to a slower trickle-down where each sand pixel has to wait for an air pixel to appear beneath it, leading to alternate air-sand falling down slower, hope this is clear.)

Now my question is, if I have other pixel types that move up, like smoke or steam, then it feels like everything is inverted and the update order should be top-down!

Now I don't see how to run the update both to-down and bottom-up at the same time. Is there a "standard" solution to this problem? Can double-buffering help, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the technicalities of simulation design, but it seems to me that you could update all the sand-like particles from the bottom up, and then update all the steam-like particles from the top down. This means that if steam and sand would try and enter the same spot then the sand would always win, but unless you are planning some very weird physics, that's an intuitive result.

Alternatively, make the artistic decision that steam rises more slowly and spaced out than sand does in your simulation.

Answer (score 1):

The default method is to just always process cells from bottom-left to top-right to handle the problem of realistic physics. One particular youtuber MARF has documented his process for this in the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ka3tbbT-9E), including vertically travelling particles.

At no point does he nor anyone else recommend any different form of per-pixel traversal for processing other than bottom-left to top-right. You give and you take. Double buffering would help, but would not be worth the excess processing time to accomplish it.

The only thing I would note is that you should utilize the power of JFAs (jumpflood surfaces) and SDFs (signed-distance fields) for distance checks rather than doing per-pixel texture fetches. You can generate a JFA/SDF of an image, see [this GODOT 2D GI article](https://samuelbigos.github.io/posts/2dgi1-2d-global-illumination-in-godot.html) for information.

This works well because empty space will give you the distance to the nearest surface and... we don't need to check the status of empty space anyways.